# Скрыть командную строку при загрузке webdriver в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cmd

Как скрыть открывающиеся окно при загрузке `chromedriver`?

Comment: Что за библиотека? Это `Selenium`?

Comment: Да, Selenium , при загрузке webdrivera обязательно вылазиет командная строка....

Comment: Нашел это, но это C#. `var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());`